# Oracle query conversion to Impala equivalent query

Tags: sql, oracle, impala

I have an oracle query that needs to be converted into Impala equivalent.

The problem with this query is that the Impala does not support select statement in Join condition with ON.

Also when I tried to put it in where clause, I am getting subqueries in OR predicates are not supported.

Please help me in the equivalent conversion of the below Oracle query:

```
select distinct t6.id, app.id, app.name, app.col ,'Yes or No' as type
from table4 t4
join table5 t5 on t4.id =t5.id and (t5.col1 is null or t5.col2 in (select distinct id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
join table6 t6 on t5.id =t6.id and (t6.col1 is null or t6.col2 in (select distinct id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
join table7 t7 on t7.id =t4.id and t7.id= t6.id and (t7.col1 is null or t7.col2 in (select distinct id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
join table8 app on t7.id = app.id
```

My approach to convert it into impala equivalent which **did not work** getting this error **subqueries in OR predicates are not supported**

```
select distinct t6.id, app.id, app.name, app.col ,'Yes or No' as type
from table4 t4
join table5 t5 on t4.id =t5.id 
join table6 t6 on t5.id =t6.id 
join table7 t7 on t7.id =t4.id and t7.id= t6.id
join table8 app on t7.id = app.id
WHERE (t5.col1 is null or t5.col2 in (select id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
   AND (t6.col1 is null or t6.col2 in (select id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
 AND (t7.col1 is null or t7.col2 in (select id from unique_table ut where "somecondition")  )
```

Please help me out in converting it into Impala equivalent as I am out of my ideas and really need to convert it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyway it is likely to be a poor performing query in any database because of `or` condition with subquery in the `join` clause. It would be better to do `left join` this additional table to each joined table and check for nulls

Comment: Hi, could you suggest any way where i can do it better like how to write the code in effiicient way. I tried left join but there is huge count diff and due to that the query is taking longer time in impala compared to oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can convert subquery to join. But issue is the join must produce unique records.

For example, if `Left join (select distinct id from unique_table) ut1 on "somecondition"` returns multiple rows for single row in t4, your query will take time. Now, if all these tables are small, you're fine else you can think to split the code into 3 separate joins.

Another note, i assumed above table is going to produce diff rows for diff joins so i joined separately, but if its same for all the joins, use only one.

```
select distinct t6.id, app.id, app.name, app.col ,'Yes or No' as type
from table4 t4
Left join (select distinct id from unique_table) ut1 on "somecondition"
join table5 t5 on t4.id =t5.id and (t5.col1 is null or t5.col2 =ut1.id  )
Left join (select distinct id from unique_table) ut2 on "somecondition"
join table6 t6 on t5.id =t6.id and (t6.col1 is null or t6.col2=ut2.id)
Left join (select distinct id from unique_table) ut3 on "somecondition"
join table7 t7 on t7.id =t4.id and t7.id= t6.id and (t7.col1 is null or t7.col2 =ut3.id )
join table8 app on t7.id = app.id
```